# Portable software in Linux

Tags: portable, grive

Can someone tell me how to create a portable application. I want to create a portable application of Grive client. In my school I don't have the right to install anything.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system do you want the portable app to run on?

Comment: For `In my school I don't have the right to install anything.`, you may need to set apt-get to use a proxy. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy). I find Java is a useful way to do a small and portable application, as it will run on most machines. What problems do you have creating a portable application?

Comment: @Aaron  Fedora 15

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "portable"?  In the programming community, it means "can be made to run on different kinds of systems", which seems to be how the other commenters have interpreted it.  Some software developers, however, use it to mean "can be run without installing it", which seems to me to be more in line with your comment about privileges on school computers.

Comment: I mean "can be run without installing it".